# Two different tickHeights on a rating scale in Psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

I know that you can customize the tickHeight on rating scales in Psychopy. I want to have two different tickHeights. here's a rough sketch:

[image: Here's a rough sketch:]

is this possible? and if so, how do I do it?

This is the code for the rating scale that I have so far:

```
myRatingScale = visual.RatingScale(myWin, precision=10, showValue=True, low = 1, high = 10, scale ="", tickHeight=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not easy. If you have a rating scale `rs` like this:

```
rs = visual.RatingScale( ... lots of parameters here ...)
```

you can create a new line with whatever tick marks as a set of vertices, and then do

```
newVertices = [ [x1,y1], .... [xn,yn] ]  # many x,y points -- all up to you
rs.line.setVertices(newVertices)
```

And only then draw the rating scale. I have not tested this but think it will work (or something similar will).